# Can't get Chrome Remote Desktop running via SSH ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, ssh

I'm trying to start running Screaming Frog in the Google Cloud Platform console using the steps [on the ScreamingFrog website](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider-cloud/#whatyou) but I'm having trouble getting the Remote Desktop to run in SSH. Every time I enter `DISPLAY= /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host --code="4/0AZEOvhVqPx3gYL01LCIWIK8idzut9v47hRYwL5QWi4EOhDt_JJaO0ZrPLMCs_EiMNacfCQ" --redirect-url="https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect" --name=$(hostname)`

and then enter a 6-digit pin twice, I get:

```
[0725/094427.353260:ERROR:daemon_controller_delegate_linux.cc(99)]   File "/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop", line 649
    as infile,
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[0725/094427.353287:ERROR:daemon_controller_delegate_linux.cc(207)] Failed to start host.
Couldn't start host.
```

And then when I try to verify that it's running by entering `sudo systemctl status --no-pager chrome-remote-desktop@$USER`, I get

```
sudo systemctl status --no-pager chrome-remote-desktop@$USER
● chrome-remote-desktop@myname.service - Chrome Remote Desktop instance for myname
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/chrome-remote-desktop@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: Please do not create duplicate [posts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/752367/256097).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're doing everything right and Google has pushed a faulty package here. Chrome remote desktop used to work for me before but when I updated the Debian package recently this error started to appear. From the looks of it it's a faulty python script.

I managed to fix it by manually changing the script, note though that that's usually not a good idea because you're editing stuff that was installed by a debian package.

What you can do is open the file `/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop`, for example with vim (you'll need sudo most likely):

`sudo vim /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop`

and reformat the code near line 645 to the following (indentations matter in Python!)

```
try:
  for config_file in ["pipewire.conf", "pipewire-pulse.conf",
                      self.pipewire_session_manager + ".conf"]:
      with open(os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, config_file + ".template"), "r") as infile:
          with open(os.path.join(runtime_path, config_file), "w") as outfile:
              template = string.Template(infile.read())
              outfile.write(template.substitute({
                    "instance_name": instance_name,
                    "runtime_path": runtime_path,
                    "sink_name": sink_name}))

  logging.info("Launching pipewire")
```

Answer (score 0):

***Below are the reasons to get this error:***

1. In your GCP project under firewalls check whether the
   `default-allow-rdp is allowed or denied`.
   **Navigation to check** : Go to your respective project > click on VPN Network > firewalls under these firewalls there will be some default rules that are allocated and check accordingly.
2. Follow this official doc to
   [configure_and_start_the_chrome_remote_desktop_service](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine#configure_and_start_the_chrome_remote_desktop_service)

> Below command is used to set up and start the Chrome Remote Desktop
> service on your VM instance, linking it with your Google Account using
> the authorization code:
>
> DISPLAY= /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host 
> --code="4/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
> --redirect-url="https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect" 
> --name=$(hostname)
>
> **Note: The authorization code in the command line is valid for only a few minutes, and you can use it only once. So, kindly check on this
> and try to reinstall again.**

3. As per the sudo systemctl status , your service is not enabled due to this you are getting `Active: inactive (dead)`. Follow this
   [troubleshooting doc](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine#troubleshooting) to re-enable the service

Let me know if the issue is still persisting after referring to the above steps.

Comment: hi, the issue is indeed still persisting. And just double-checking you mean 'VPC Network' not VPN right?

Comment: VPC Network only in which firewalls rule default-allow-rdp is set to allowed.

Comment: Hi, I was able to run screaming frog without the google chrome remote desktop using this link https://github.com/myawesomebike/SF-CLI-GCP